# SC.SceneView animated vertically?

Tags: sproutcore, css-transitions

do you see any solution for this? 
I would like to get the [SC.SceneView](http://sproutcore.com/docs/#doc=SC.SceneView&src=false) transition from bottom to top and not from left to right or right to left.

The Doc isn't saying much here, but since the original transistion has to be somewhere, maybe i can prototype its method for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, there are no options to animate horizontally.  You could create a subclass to do it (doesn't look complicated), using the existing source as a guide.

However, this doesn't appear to be using the Animation framework or `adjust` methods.  You could probably define your own that works better, using css3.  That method will work better (i.e. the animation should be smoother)

Comment: As a note, Sproutcore includes jQuery as a dependency, so you could also use jQuery to manage the animation. I have done that a few time in my SC projects, and it works pretty well.